# How to Implement Push Notifications in a PWA without Third-Party Tools?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps, android-notifications

I am working on a Progressive Web Application (PWA) and am interested in implementing push notifications to enhance user engagement. However, I am keen on achieving this without relying on third-party services or tools for sending push notifications.

Here's what I am aiming for:

- I want to send push notifications to users even when the **app is not active** or in the foreground.
- I prefer to handle this feature on my own, without involving any third-party services like Firebase Cloud Messaging or other push notification services.
- The notifications should only be sent to the PWA, not the main website.
- I am open to leveraging service workers, the Push API, and the Notifications API, but I am not sure how to set up the backend part to handle the push notifications independently.
- I have come across the Web Periodic Background Sync API and wonder if this could be a viable solution for sending notifications on a scheduled basis. However, I am unsure of its browser support and reliability for my use case.
- I am looking for a simple solution, without the complicated servers etc, just code on my site, something like a cheat script that will fire a push notification.
- My clients are very specific they want the notifications so I dont care about User Permissions, I can do with or without which ever is simpler.

Could anyone provide guidance or share their experiences on how to set up push notifications in a PWA, without relying on third-party tools? Any code examples, tutorials, or references would be greatly appreciated.

I have done a simple PWA and it works great, but I am struggling to follow up with the whole Push notification part so I am searching for a simpler cheat.
Anyhting that will make the phones beep/vibrate etc, and will give a line or two of info written by me.

I dont wnat to deal with VAPID, setting up servers etc, at the same time I just want to make a script that fires a notification, but only to the PWA and including not currently used apps. As there is no point to send a notification to someone who is on the site anyway.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution that wasn't too complex?

It's insane to me how overcomplicated the entire setup currently is

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a javascript/node pwa? More information regarding your platform setup would be helpful.